# StageWebView - How to prevent stretching of the bitmap obtained through drawViewPortToBitmapData?

Tags: apache-flex

I am trying to show the page displayed using `StageWebView` as a bitmap. As per the documentation we need to use `DrawViewPortToBitMapData`. While displaying the bitmap in a 
`UIComponent`, the image is getting stretched.  How can I prevent that?

```
bitmapData = new BitmapData(webView.viewPort.width, webView.viewPort.height, false,
0x000000 );
webView.drawViewPortToBitmapData(bitmapData);
webViewBmp = new Bitmap(bitmapData); 
webView.stage = null;

uiComponent = new UIComponent;
uiComponent.width=webView.viewPort.width;
uiComponent.height=webView.viewPort.height;
uiComponent.addChild(webViewBmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to apply width/height to the uicomponent.  it should be ok just by adding the bitmap to it.  What you seem to be doing is stretching the uicomponent even though you have already added the bitmap at its correct size.

Answer (score 0):

You should set scale to 1 on uiComponet. If you set applicationDPI (let's say to 160dpi), Flex is automatically scalling uiComponent according to the device DPI, setting scaleX and scaleY to runtimeDPI/160.

Try something like this:

uiComponent.scaleX=160/parentApplication.runtimeDPI;
uiComponent.scaleY=160/parentApplication.runtimeDPI;

so scaleX and scaleY ends with:

runtimeDPI/160 (done by flex) * 160/runtimeDPI = 1 :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but this worked for me:

```
        var r:Rectangle = wView.viewPort;
        var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(r.width, r.height);
        wView.drawViewPortToBitmapData(bd);
        var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bd);
        bmp.width = bd.width * (Capabilities.screenResolutionX / 320);
        bmp.height = bd.height * (Capabilities.screenResolutionY / 480);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use uiComponent.unscaledWidth & unscaledHeight. This is my working component, altered flexcapacitor code - original here: http://flexcapacitor.googlecode.com/svn-history/r5/trunk/mobilelibrary/src/com/flexcapacitor/controls/WebView.as

look at takeSnapshot:

```
    snapshotBitmapData = new BitmapData(_webView.viewPort.width, _webView.viewPort.height);
    webView.drawViewPortToBitmapData(snapshotBitmapData);
    webViewBitmap = new Bitmap(snapshotBitmapData);
    webViewBitmap.width = unscaledWidth;
    webViewBitmap.height = unscaledHeight;
    addChild(webViewBitmap);
    hideWebView();
```

full code:

```
package ctrls {

import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.events.ErrorEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.FocusEvent;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.LocationChangeEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.media.StageWebView;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
import mx.core.UIComponent;

/** @copy flash.media.StageWebView#ErrorEvent.ERROR */
[Event(name="error", type="flash.events.ErrorEvent")]
/** @copy flash.media.StageWebView#Event.COMPLETE */
[Event(name="complete", type="flash.events.Event")]
/** @copy flash.media.StageWebView#LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGING */
[Event(name="locationChanging", type="flash.events.LocationChangeEvent")]
/** @copy flash.media.StageWebView#LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGE */
[Event(name="locationChange", type="flash.events.LocationChangeEvent")]

/**
 * This class wraps the standard StageWebView with a UIComponent.
 * This allows it to be sized and positioned in the same way
 * any UIComponent would. <br/><br/>
 *
 * The StageWebView class documentation follows:<br/>
 * @copy flash.media.StageWebView
 * */
public class WebView extends UIComponent {

//==================================================================================================

protected var _webView:StageWebView;
private var _source:String;
private var _visibleChanged:Boolean;
private var _sourceChanged:Boolean;

/** @copy flash.media.StageWebView#viewPort */
public function get viewPort():Rectangle { return _webView ? _webView.viewPort : null; }
/** @copy flash.media.StageWebView#dispose() */
public function dispose():void { hideWebView(true); }
/** @copy flash.media.StageWebView#assignFocus() */
public function assignFocus(direction:String = "none"):void { webView.assignFocus(direction); }
/** @copy flash.media.StageWebView#drawViewPortToBitmapData() */
public function drawViewPortToBitmapData(bitmap:BitmapData):void { webView.drawViewPortToBitmapData(bitmap); }
/** @copy flash.media.StageWebView#title */
public function get title():String { return _webView ? _webView.title : null; }

/** @copy flash.media.StageWebView#isHistoryBackEnabled() */
public function get isHistoryBackEnabled():Boolean { return _webView ? _webView.isHistoryBackEnabled : false; }
/** @copy flash.media.StageWebView#isHistoryForwardEnabled() */
public function get isHistoryForwardEnabled():Boolean { return _webView ? _webView.isHistoryForwardEnabled : false; }
/** @copy flash.media.StageWebView#historyBack() */
public function historyBack():void { if(_webView) _webView.historyBack(); }
/** @copy flash.media.StageWebView#historyForward() */
public function historyForward():void { if(_webView) _webView.historyForward(); }
/** @copy flash.media.StageWebView#reload() */
public function reload():void { webView.reload(); }
/** @copy flash.media.StageWebView#stop() */
public function stop():void { if(_webView) webView.stop(); }
/** Load the URL passed in or load the URL specified in the source property
 *  @see flash.media.StageWebView#loadURL() */
public function load(url:String = null):void { webView.loadURL(url ? _source = url : source); }

override public function set visible(value:Boolean):void {
    super.visible = value;
    _visibleChanged = true;
    invalidateProperties();
    invalidateSize();
}
/** @private */
public function get source():String { return _source; }
/**
 * Source URL for stage web view.
 * @see flash.media.StageWebView#loadURL()
 * */
[Bindable]
public function set source(value:String):void {
    _source = value;
    _sourceChanged = true;
    invalidateProperties();
    invalidateSize();
}

//==================================================================================================

/**
 *  Wrapper for StageWebView
 *
 *  @copy flash.media.StageWebView
 */
public function WebView() {
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage);
    addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removedFromStage);
    focusEnabled = false;
}

/** @private */
public function get webView():StageWebView {
    if(!_webView) webView = new StageWebView();
    return _webView; }
/** @copy flash.media.StageWebView */
public function set webView(value:StageWebView):void {
    if(_webView == value) return;
    if(_webView) {
        _webView.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
        _webView.removeEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
        _webView.removeEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, focusInViewHandler);
        _webView.removeEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT, focusOutViewHandler);
        _webView.removeEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGING, locationChangingHandler);
        _webView.removeEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGE, locationChangeHandler); }
    _webView = value;
    _webView.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
    _webView.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
    _webView.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, focusInViewHandler);
    _webView.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT, focusOutViewHandler);
    _webView.addEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGING, locationChangingHandler);
    _webView.addEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGE, locationChangeHandler);
    _webView.stage = visible ? stage : null;
    _visibleChanged = false;
    if(source) _webView.loadURL(_source);
    _sourceChanged = false;
    invalidateDisplayList();
}
/** Hides the web view @see flash.media.StageWebView#stage */
public function hideWebView(destroy:Boolean = false):void {
    if(_webView == null) return;
    _webView.stage = null;
    if(!destroy) return;
    _webView.viewPort = null;
    _webView.dispose();
    _webView = null;
}
/** Displays the web view @see flash.media.StageWebView#stage */
public function showWebView():void {
    if(_webView != null) {
        webView.stage = stage;
        return; }
    _visibleChanged = true;
    invalidateProperties();
    invalidateSize();
    invalidateDisplayList(); }
/** @copy mx.core.UIComponent#commitProperties() */
override protected function commitProperties():void {
    super.commitProperties();
    if(_visibleChanged) {
        webView.stage =  visible ? stage : null;
        _visibleChanged = false; }
    if(_sourceChanged) {
        webView.loadURL(source);
        _sourceChanged = false; }}

//==================================================================================================

/** Flag indicating if a snapshot is being shown */
[Bindable]
public var isSnapshotVisible:Boolean;
/**
 * When calling takeSnapshot or setting snapshotMode to true this 
 * property will contain the bitmap data of the view port. 
 * */
public var snapshotBitmapData:BitmapData;
/**
 * When calling takeSnapshot or setting snapshotMode a snapshot of 
 * the Stage Web View is taken and added to the stage. This is a
 * reference to the displayed bitmap. 
 * */
public var webViewBitmap:Bitmap;
/**
 * @private
 * */
public function get snapshotMode():Boolean {
    return isSnapshotVisible;
}
/**
 * When set to true hides the stage web view and displays a non-interactive 
 * snapshot of the Stage Web View when the property was set to true.  
 * */
public function set snapshotMode(value:Boolean):void {
    value ? takeSnapshot() : removeSnapshot();
}
/**
 * Creates a snapshot of the Stage Web View at the point of this call 
 * and displays that instead of the actual Stage Web View. 
 * Use removeSnapshot to dispose of the snapshot and show the web contents again. 
 * 
 * @see isSnapshotVisible
 * @see flash.media.StageWebView#drawViewPortToBitmapData()
 * */
public function takeSnapshot():BitmapData {
    destroySnapshot();
    snapshotBitmapData = new BitmapData(_webView.viewPort.width, _webView.viewPort.height);
    webView.drawViewPortToBitmapData(snapshotBitmapData);
    webViewBitmap = new Bitmap(snapshotBitmapData);
    webViewBitmap.width = unscaledWidth;
    webViewBitmap.height = unscaledHeight;
    addChild(webViewBitmap);
    hideWebView(); 
    isSnapshotVisible = true;

    return snapshotBitmapData;
}
/**
 * Removes the bitmap snapshot of the Stage Web View from the display list 
 * and displays the actual Stage Web View.
 * @copy flash.media.StageWebView#drawViewPortToBitmapData()
 * */
public function removeSnapshot():void {
    destroySnapshot();
    showWebView();
}
/**
 * Removes the web view snapshot from the display list and disposes of the 
 * bitmap data
 * */
private function destroySnapshot():void {
    if (webViewBitmap) {
        if (webViewBitmap.parent) removeChild(webViewBitmap);
        if (webViewBitmap.bitmapData) webViewBitmap.bitmapData.dispose();
        webViewBitmap = null;
    }
    if (snapshotBitmapData) {
        snapshotBitmapData.dispose();
        snapshotBitmapData = null;
    }
    isSnapshotVisible = false;
}

//==================================================================================================

/**
 * If enabled adds support for the back and search keys.
 * Back key navigates back in web view history and search navigates forward.
 * */
public var navigationSupport:Boolean;
/**
 * If enabled adds a keyboard listener to the stage.
 * This handles when the component does not have focus
 * */
public var addKeyHandlerToStage:Boolean;
/**
 * KeyCode to use when navigation support is enabled.
 * Default is Keyboard.BACK
 * */
public var backKeyCode:int = Keyboard.BACK;
/**
 * KeyCode to use when navigation support is enabled.
 * Default is Keyboard.SEARCH
 * */
public var forwardKeyCode:int = Keyboard.SEARCH;
/**
 * @copy mx.core.UIComponent#measure()
 * */
override protected function measure():void {
    super.measure();

    measuredWidth=480;
    measuredMinWidth=120;
    measuredHeight=320;
    measuredMinHeight=160;
}
/**
 * @copy mx.core.UIComponent#updateDisplayList()
 * */
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
// NOTE: IF THE WEBVIEW IS NOT BEING SIZED CORRECTLY
// check if focusEnabled is true. If it is then the soft keyboard may not be dispatching the
// deactivate event because the webview has focus when it is dispatched. set to false
// position according to the container rather than the stage
    var runtimeDPI:int = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.runtimeDPI;
    var applicationDPI:int = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.applicationDPI;
    var point:Point = localToGlobal(new Point());
    var scaleFactor:Number = runtimeDPI / applicationDPI;
    var scaledWidth:int = width * scaleFactor;
    var scaledHeight:int = height * scaleFactor;
    webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(point.x, point.y, scaledWidth, scaledHeight);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  Event handlers
//
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

/** When the stage property is available add it to the web view */
public function addedToStage(event:Event):void {
//  adds support for keyboard events when not in focus
    if (navigationSupport && addKeyHandlerToStage)
        stage.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
    _visibleChanged = true;
    invalidateProperties();
    invalidateDisplayList();
}
/** When removed from the stage remove the web view */
protected function removedFromStage(event:Event):void {
    hideWebView();
//  removes support for keyboard events when not in focus
    if (navigationSupport && addKeyHandlerToStage)
        stage.removeEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler );
}
/** Dispatches a focus in event when the web view gains focus. */
protected function focusInViewHandler(event:FocusEvent):void {
    //webView.assignFocus();

    if (hasEventListener(event.type))
        dispatchEvent(event);

}
/** Dispatches a focus out event when the web view gains focus. */
protected function focusOutViewHandler(event:FocusEvent):void {
    //webView.assignFocus(FocusDirection.TOP);

    if (hasEventListener(event.type))
        dispatchEvent(event);
}
/** Dispatches a focus in event when the web view gains focus. */
override protected function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {

    if (navigationSupport) {
        if (event.keyCode == backKeyCode && webView.isHistoryBackEnabled ) {
            webView.historyBack();
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        if (navigationSupport && event.keyCode == forwardKeyCode && webView.isHistoryForwardEnabled ) {
            webView.historyForward();
        }
    }

    super.keyDownHandler(event);
}

/** Dispatched when the page or web content has been fully loaded */
protected function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
    if(hasEventListener(event.type)) dispatchEvent(event); }
/** Dispatched when the location is about to change */
protected function locationChangingHandler(event:Event):void {
    if(hasEventListener(event.type)) dispatchEvent(event); }
/** Dispatched when the location has changed */
protected function locationChangeHandler(event:Event):void {
    if(hasEventListener(event.type)) dispatchEvent(event); }
/** Dispatched when an error occurs */
protected function errorHandler(event:ErrorEvent):void {
    if(hasEventListener(event.type)) dispatchEvent(event); }

}}
```